# Why does the "TypeError: client.db is not a function" appear on Node.js and how do I fix it?

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

I was minding my business until I stumble upon this TypeError. I tried my best to figure it out, but the codes won't work in my method.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const objectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
require("dotenv/config");

let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true }));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

app.listen(4000, () => {
console.log("It's connected to the server!");
mongoClient.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (client, err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw error
    };
    const dB = client.db(process.env.DB_NAME); //Not a function, why?
    dB.collection("cookie");
    console.log(`Connected to "${process.env.DB_NAME}" !`);
});
```

});

I hope I get some good advice on how to tackle the problem properly. :)

Answer (score 2):

The callback for `mongoClient.connect` has the wrong order of arguments.

`(client, err) => {...}` should be `(err, client) => {...}`

Either it receives a real error or `null`, but any of them should not have a function called `db` on them.